# python dictionary myd problems

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Consider a dictionary that keeps the first names as keys and ages as values: myf = {"Amy":19, "Mary":18, "Bill":21, "Cate":23, "Zack":20}

A) Write a python code that will create a new dictionary myg, which does not contain students, whose names starts with letters "A" or "M" or "S".

B) Break the dictionary myf into two dictionaries myf1 and myf2 such that myf1 contains only those students whose ages are less than and equal to 10 and whose name starts with letters "M-Z", while myf2 contains the rest.

```
These are my attempts: 

A) n = len(myf)
for i = 1:n
    if myf[i] = "A", "R", "S"

B) myf = myf1 + myf2
for i in myf1
    myf1 = myf <= 10
else: 
     myf2
```

My understanding of A is weaker than B. I understand what each question is asking, I am just not sure how to formulate a working code for each. Anyone that can help me fix my codes will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Solution for A:

```
>>> dict((key, value) for key, value in myf.items() if key[0] not in ['A', 'M', 'S'])
>>> myg
{'Bill': 21, 'Zack': 20, 'Cate': 23}
```

Solution for B(note: ages are less than and equal to 10 will get an empty dict, I change it to 20 so you can have a better feeling about how the actual result should be)

```
>>> import string
>>> mtoz = string.ascii_uppercase[12:]
>>> mtoz
'MNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> myf1 = dict((key, value) for key, value in myf.items() if key[0] in mtoz and value <= 20)
>>> myf1
{'Mary': 18, 'Zack': 20}
>>> myf2 = dict(item for item in myf.items() if item not in myf1.items())
>>> myf2
{'Amy': 19, 'Bill': 21, 'Cate': 23}
```

Answer (score 0):

A

```
myg = {}
for key in myf:
  if key[0] not in {'A','R','S'}: myg[key] = myf[key]
```

B

```
myf1 = {}
myf2 = {}
for key in myf:
 if key[0] >= 'M' and myf[key] <= 10: 
  myf1[key] = myf[key]
 else: myf2[key] = myf[key]
```